# Magic Keyboard + Windows 10 -- disable fn lock?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I have used an apple wireless keyboard (not the "magic" variety) for some years on my windows 10 running on a macbook pro. I upgraded to the Magic Keyboard and I am seeing a strange behavior.

In windows <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> is the equivalent of the <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> respectively. Additionally, if I do that same combination but add shift, so, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd>, I can highlight the entire line. Very handy!

On the new Magic Keyboard, when I do <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> (with or without arrow keys), it locks the shift and it acts as if it is being held down until I press shift again. In fact, this works with control/command as well.

Does anyone know how to disable this functionality? I think this is maybe called fn lock but googling it so far has been unfruitful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So, I couldn't tell you why or how, but I downloaded this software:

https://magicutilities.net/download

After installing it, this "feature" went away and the fn key no longer caused other modifier keys to become sticky. Downside is there's a yearly fee for this software, so if anyone has any other ideas I'd love to hear them!

Comment: did you figure something better out?